# WHERE NOT EXISTS check and equals to "=" check fail together but work seperatly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, where-clause, not-exists

I have an INSERT SQL query which needs to check if the entry will cause double booking, and that also the 2 users (doctor and patient) are affiliated with the same clinic. (Found it easier to explain in regard to the scenario), the SQL I have is:

```
WITH ins (MedStaffID, PatientID, TimeSlot, AppDate)
    AS (SELECT 1, 6, 10, DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
INSERT INTO Appointments (MedStaffID, PatientID, TimeSlot, AppDate) 
SELECT ins.MedStaffID, ins.PatientID, ins.TimeSlot, ins.AppDate
FROM ins
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM Appointments 
    WHERE (MedStaffID = ins.MedStaffID OR PatientID = ins.PatientID)
    AND TimeSlot = TimeSlot 
    AND AppDate = ins.AppDate
)
AND 
(
    SELECT Clinic 
    FROM Users UD
    WHERE UD.ID = ins.MedStaffID
)
= 
(
    SELECT Clinic 
    FROM Users UD
    WHERE UD.ID = ins.PatientID
);
```

The 2 WHERE checks function correctly without the other, but when together always results in the INSERT not proceeding even if it should pass both checks.

Example Users Table:

```
ID    Clinic    Role    Forename    n'otherstuff
1       1      Doctor     Bob         Potato
2       1      Patient    Jim          Cake
3       1      Patient   Laura         Tart
4       2      Doctor    Sally        Muffin
5       2      Patient   Khaaan        Lolly
```

Example Appointments Table:

```
ID    MedStaffID    PatientID    TimeSlot    Date
1        1              2            1       *today
2        1              2            2       *today
3        1              3            4       *today
4        4              5            2       *today
```

So the insert needs to prevent another appointment for a doctor if he already has an appointment for that time and date, likewise for a patient.

It also needs to ensure the doctor and patient are with the same clinic.

Individually the checks do their jobs, but I need them to work together, and also another check will be needed to ensure the ID placed in the "MedStaffID" field is tied to a User with "Role" "Doctor", but right now I'm stumped at these 2 checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just want to join directly?

```
WITH ins (MedStaffID, PatientID, TimeSlot, AppDate)
    AS (SELECT 1, 6, 10, DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
INSERT INTO Appointments (MedStaffID, PatientID, TimeSlot, AppDate)
  SELECT ins.MedStaffID, ins.PatientID, ins.TimeSlot, ins.AppDate
    FROM ins
    JOIN Users Staff ON (Staff.ID = ins.MedStaffID)
    JOIN Users Patient ON (Patient.ID = ins.PatientID)
    WHERE Staff.Clinic = Patient.Clinic
      AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                    FROM Appointments 
                    WHERE (MedStaffID = ins.MedStaffID OR PatientID = ins.PatientID)
                      AND TimeSlot = TimeSlot 
                      AND AppDate = ins.AppDate
                 )
;
```

Comment: ah thanks that works, didn't think of this, do you know why having them setup like I did doesn't work though, curious.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the problem for sure. However...

1. In the not-exists code, shouldn't:

   ```
   AND TimeSlot = TimeSlot
   ```

be

```
    AND TimeSlot = ins.TimeSlot
```

2. As an optimization step, the ClinicID checks should come first. Where-not-exists is typically a full-table-scan (or full index scan). If the table is always small, that's not an issue.
3. As an optimization step, the where-not-exists subclause should select id, not *.
4. It should not be the case, but it might be the case, since I can't find anything else, that operator-precedence is biting you. Add parentheses around your ClinicID check (the whole expression).
5. `Explain Query` is your friend.